# Handlebars: More than one model inside template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am starting with Handlebars, and was wondering:

> Is there the possibility to pass more than one model to the view?

I am passing my model with `$(template(model))` to the view:

```
    var source = $('#template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var model = this.model.toJSON();
    $(template(model)).appendTo(this.$parent);
```

So I can pass one variable with stored JSON data to the view. But what if I want to have two different variables/models in one template?

Is this possible? This would be much easier than generating another template and loading into the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A compiled Handlebars template just wants an object as its argument, you can build that object however you want. If you want two models, just add an extra level of indirection:

```
var html  = template({
    model: this.model.toJSON(),
    other: this.other_model.toJSON()
});
```

and then inside your template you can say things like:

```
{{model.attribute}}
{{other.other_attribute}}
```

and the like.

---

As an aside, a Backbone view adding HTML to anything other than `this.$el` (i.e. `this.$parent`) is a bit dodgy. Events are bound to `this.$el` so events won't work without help. You'll probably an easier time if you turn that around a bit so that the parent places your view's `$el` somewhere so that your view can be self contained.